# OS X: Copy a user account from one computer to another?

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I'm traveling for a week and will be borrowing my roommate's laptop. We both have Macs running Snow Leopard. How can I copy my entire user account (files, settings, etc.) over to his computer?

Is it as simple as creating a new user account and copying over my home folder? Do I have to do more?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it as simple as creating a new user account and copying over my home folder?

Yes, but do it in the opposite order: Copy your home folder to his /Users; then create a user account on his machine with the same short-name as your home folder name.  When creating the new user account, OS-X will notice the existing yourname folder and ask whether to use it for the new account.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Migration Assistant and have a Firewire cable, your Mac will take care of the whole process. Just sit back and relax.

Migration Assistant can be found in `/Applications/Utilities`